# How to best write a "Trim" expression

Tags: function, ms-access, texttrimming

What I'm trying to do is trim an FQDN down to just the name of the asset.

For example, let's say I have a machine called `"Desktop1.mycompany.com"` and I just want to have the value `"Desktop1"` in another field.

I've done a trim command `Trim(Left([ColumnwithFQDN],(InsStr(1,[ColumnwithFQDN],".")-1)))` and it works. It removes everything but the machine name.

However, I notice this list has some computer names without the FQDN and they're just showing up as `"Desktop2"`. Obviously, this causes a `#Func! error`.

My question is: is there any way to either skip anything that's not in the FQDN or have it just return the original value if the function fails?

I think I could do an `IIf(IsNull)` command, but I'm not sure what I would be setting as the value to return.

Comment: I guess I just associated "trim" with an existing Excel command that I incorporated from an existing spreadsheet. It had a trim command that did what I wanted, but maybe the command was used out of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Trim` function removes leading and trailing spaces from a string, and neither a hostname nor an FQDN can contain such, so that function isn't needed here. Of course, you can apply it in the end, if you wish. The interesting part is the `Left` function in this case. I suggest to use the following expression:

```
Left([ColumnwithFQDN], Len([ColumnwithFQDN]) - InStrRev(StrReverse([ColumnwithFQDN]), "."))
```

Same as with the solution of @HansUp, you have to be sure that `[ColumnwithFQDN]` isn't Null.